# Building a flash message service with Angular and Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to create a service in my Angular 5 project that will handle the display of flash messages to the user. I'm happy enough using observables created by the likes of HttpClient, but I've never got my head around how to create and use my own.

What seems like the logical path is to have an Observable exposed on the service, a UI component that subscribes to and displays data from said observable as it emits, and other parts of the application can send messages *to* that observable.

I can subscribe to the observable and display data, but how do I set an observable up to be sent data to pass along? Am I even going about this the right way?

My efforts so far have been to use a `Subject`, but this doesn't seem to be working. Simplified code below.

```js
// flash.service
const flash: Subject = new Subject();
function sendToFlash(message) {
    flash.next(message);
}

// some.component
flashService.flash.subscribe(message => {
    doThingsWithMessage(message);
)

ngOnChanges(changes) {
    flashService.sendToFlash('Oooh, changes happened');
}
```

No errors are thrown but the subscribers don't seem to get the message that's been sent.

Comment: are you looking something like `toaster` ?.'

Comment: Quite probably, but I'd rather use the chance to learn how to do this with RxJS :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! My code was actually correct, but the component sending the message was in a different module (with a distinct provider set up) and so - I think - multiple services (and thus observables) were running in parallel. The sender and subscriber weren't listening to the same observable.

TL;DR, make sure you don't have the flash service provided more than once! Providing it at my top-level module sufficed for me.